# Use of wifi direct to send message in Windows Form Application

Tags: winforms, wifi-direct

I want to make a windows form applcation using c# which will send message between to pcs using Wi-Fi direct.Can I use wifi direct library for windows form application?If I can,please let me know how?

Comment: "I want to make a windows form applcation using c# which will send message between to pcs using Wi-Fi direct." is  a statement. What is your question?

Comment: Can I use wifi direct library for windows form application?If I can,let me know how

Comment: Did you try google? Please tell what you got so far.

Comment: Yes, I did it.But I only found wifi direct library for windows store app.But I want to build windows form application @AsimKT

Comment: Please state what have you found so far, and what is your correct problem in questions so that you will get better answers.

Comment: I have done it using wlan connection

Answer (score 0):

no you cannot use wifi direct library for windows form for desktop apps. as the namespace Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect is only provided for windows runtime api.

Wifi direct is not implemented natively in Windows 7 or older windows o.s.
But Starting on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012, Wi-Fi Direct functions were added to the Native Wifi API.

This is the link which will provide you all the features which are available. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn457945(v=vs.85).aspx

Here's a presentation that goes over the feature in detail: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/HW-329T.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I want to build a desktop app which can send message between two laptop using wifi but will not use any internet or server, what should I do?

Comment: there are many ways to do this. you can use sockets, tcp connections to send your files. there are lot of examples on the internet.  the basics is if you dont want to use internet,both devices should be connected within the same network.

Comment: If it is not possible without connecting to the same network then how does 'shareIt' work?

Comment: devices connected to this network can only participate in data sharing. in one device shareit app acts as a server and at another it acts like a client.

Comment: Can I use this concept to build my app?